# Use Screen commands (C-A C-C, etc.) in byobu-tmux

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux, byobu

I was having some troubles with `byobu` lately while using the `screen` back-end, so I switched to using the `tmux` back-end, which works like a charm.

The problem is now that my keyboard has tiny <kbd>F1</kbd>­-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys, so it's hard to use them without looking at the keyboard. I'd like to continue using <kbd>Cltr</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Cltr</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for new screen, etc. Is there a way to re-map these to the tmux-specific keys?

I'm using Konsole as my terminal emulator and Awesome as my window manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading a bunch of man-pages, I figured out that adding the line

```
set -g prefix C-A
```

to `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf` changes the escape sequence. This way, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> does what it would do in `screen`. Only problem is now that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> doesn't, but that's fine, it can be changed by changing key bindings one-by-one in the `.tmux.conf` file:

```
bind-key C-C new-window
bind-key C-A last-window
bind-key C-Space next-window
```